# Website / ftp management software with easy ACL

Tags: ftp

I need to create users and give them ftp access to a specific paths (e.g. mike -> /var/www/html/mike ; bob -> /var/www/html/bob ) 
 I'm using Centos / linux server. Is there any plug & play solution ? I've played around a bit with ftpd but couldn't set proper user access as specified above.

Answer (score 0):

I always use vsftpd it has excellent access control for both real and virtual users, you can also set their FTP directories no matter if the user exists or not.

https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html

and a nice installation tutorial http://linuxforfun.net/2008/04/05/vsftpd-virtual-users/

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed [ISPConfig 3](http://www.ispconfig.org/ispconfig-3/) on my Centos VPS and it's been brilliant. It takes some configuring but once that's done you'll be impressed with what it can do.

I used [this tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-centos-6.2-x86_64-with-apache2-ispconfig-3) when setting my server up. It's a good read and very helpeful.